# Passing TextBox's text to another form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried this to pass the information:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1(); 
 textBox1.Text = ((TextBox)frm1.Controls["textBox1"]).Text;
```

This is in the form load of the form getting the information. But there is no text. How do I fix this? `Form2` is grabbing `Form1`'s text and displaying it.

Comment: @EliteGamer: How do you obtain the reference `frm1`? Can you post that code too?

Comment: is the textbox in `Form1` initialized with a value in the `Text` property? if not then that is why your `textBox.Text` is empty. How are you expecting the text to appear in `textBox1`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Expose the contents of the textbox using a property:

```
class Form1 {
  public string MyValue {
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
  }
}
```

Then in Form2 do this:

```
var frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.ShowDialog(this); // make sure this instance of Form1 is visible
textBox1.Text = frm1.MyValue;
```

If you want `frm1` to be constantly visible then make `frm1` a class variable of `Form2`, and call `.Show()` in the constructor of `Form2` for example.

Answer (score 5):

I find Easy and Logical Way to Passing Text value one textbox to other in Windows Application.

**In Second Form Write Code:-**

```
    Create a Parameter of *Form2* Constructor.

    namespace PassingValue
    {
         public partial class Form2 : Form
         {
             public Form2(string message)
             {
                 InitializeComponent();
                 Textbox1.Text= message;
             }
         }
    }
```

**In First Form Write Code:-**

```
   Use the Parameter of Second Form in *First Form*:-

   namespace PassValue
   {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
         public Form1()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Form2 f2=new Form2(Textbox.Text);
             f2.Show();
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following code , its work for me...

```
    public static string sendtext = "";
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
sendtext = txt1.Text;
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Show();
}
```

access this data in the form load event of form2

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
txt2.Text = Form1.sendtext;
}
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Form 1

```
//Declare a Static variable
public static string txtInput=string.empty;`

//Set textBox Value to this variable on any event
txtInput=textBox1.Text;
```

Form 2

```
// Now Call this variable from the Instance of form 1
string getForm1Value=string.empty;
getForm1Value=Form1.txtinput;
```

Answer (score 1):

**

> 100% Working

**

Take 2 forms, Form1 and Form2 ,  Form1 contain textbox1 and Frm1Btn1, and Form2 contain Frm2Btn1, now open form1, click on  open the form2

//FORM1 CODING:

```
private void Frm1Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    Form2 obj=new Form2();
    obj.showDialog();
}
```

//FORM2 CODING:

```
private void Frm2Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form1 objj = new Form1();

            objj =(Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

            objj.textBox1.Text = "Salil";

            objj=null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest approach is like this:

1. Change your Textbox modifiers property to Public;
2. where you open your 2nd form, open It like this: **frm.Show(this);**
3. in your Form2, wherever you need text, just do this:

> ```
> var frm = this.Owner;
> var ctl = frm.Controls.Find("textboxOnform1", true).FirstOrDefault() as 
>     Control;
> TextBox Txt = (TextBox)ctl; 
>
> //And then you can use It 
> textboxt1.Text= Txt.Text;
> ```

You can do opposite - send text back  - in same way.

Answer (score 0):

If its a web form MSDN suggests this at the top of the page requesting text.

```
     <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>
```

then this in page_load

```
    if (PreviousPage != null)
{
TextBox SourceTextBox = 
    (TextBox) PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
if (SourceTextBox != null)
{
    Label1.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;
}
}
```

Comment: ill just leave this here in case someone comes across this question using webforms

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Form1's textBox1.Text property is initialized to an *actual string* that you can see. I suspect that, since you're using a default instance of Form1, the TextBox1.Text property is [String.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is the default value (and why you're not getting any visible text which it seems is what you're expecting).

Answer (score 0):

An easy thing which you can do is to store the textbox value into a variable and then pass it to another form using constructor. E.G

```
string textboxvalue=textbox1.Text();
form2 win = new form2(textboxvalue);
```

here form2 is the form where you want to send the value and win is the instance of that form.

Answer (score 0):

In windows application., Just go to another form designer and declare that tool as public. You can access that tool from any form.

Answer (score 0):

This is on the result form:

1. Put a textBox.
2. You must click the form until the code editor pop out.
3. On the form load, you insert the code.

Code:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.Show();
textBox1.Text = ((TextBox)frm1.Controls["textBox1"]).Text;
```

On the first form:

1. Put a textBox and a button.

Button code (at Form Load, enter this code):

```
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

in form1 : hotcoffee

pass the textbox
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//get item on creditcard

```
    {
            this.Hide();
            hotcoffepayment p = new otcoffepayment(richTextBox2.Text);//pass form1 textbox
            p.Show();
    }
```

in form2 :hotcoffepayment

public hotcoffepayment(string strValue)

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = strValue;//here mention the form2 textbox name 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make modifer property of textbox as "public" in order to get its value from another form

Answer (score -1):

Form 1

```
 class Form1
    {

        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1; // we need to make it public Textbox
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
```

In Form2 on Button click or any other event use

Form 2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            Form1 _form1 = new Form1();
            this._form2TextBox.Text = _form1.textBox1.Text;
 }
```

for more details visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6525896%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: While this works and is better than searching the `Controls` collection for a specific control name (e.g. because renaming the control in the Forms Designer won't break this code), if you do this kind of thing a lot, you will end up with code that is not very legible, nor particularly easy to maintain. Shouldn't be a problem in a small code base, though.

Comment: -1: even though @stakx mentioned it and you agree, I have to downvote. I disagree with this practice, even *in a small code base*. It is a bad practice to get into and I wish that the designer didn't even give you the option. There are much better ways to provide the requested functionality.