# How to pass TextBox values from one window to a ListView in another window?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, visual-studio-2012, textbox

I would like to know if there's a way where you pass TextBox values from one window to a ListView in another window.

Thanks Everyone. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165537/passing-textboxs-text-to-another-form-in-c

Comment: When you say window what do you mean exactly? Are you talking about from one form to another or are you asking about two instances of the same app?

Comment: From one form to another.