# Pass value of TextBox to another Form C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to pass texbox `username` value to another form name `FormPassword`. I try this code in `FormPassword.cs`:

```
    string strUserName;

    public string passvalue
    {
        get { return strUserName; }
        set { strUserName = value; }

    }
```

in first form from which I want to get value of `username.text`

`FormPassword frm = new FormPassword();
frm.passvalue = username.Text;`

but it give Nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send values from one form to another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form)

Comment: Your approach seems to be fine. You need to show more of your code. How are you reading the value inside `FormPassword ` ?

Comment: code for reading  value   `string uname;
            uname = strUserName;`

Comment: when i am debugging `FormPassword frm = new FormPassword();`
`frm.passvalue = username.Text;`  , username's can't assign value to `frm.passvalue`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing TextBox's text to another form in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165537/passing-textboxs-text-to-another-form-in-c)

Comment: it may b duplicate but i have tried that , but its not working for me

Comment: It _is_ a duplicate.  And there are at least three methods in that answer.  One of them _will work_ for you, if you can code it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

create parameterized constructor of second form and then pass the value to that form.